# A good English equivalent for "不過如此"?

Tags: translation

I am aiming to have a short translation, so it would be preferred that it isn't too long.

I have "Merely so" right now, but it doesn't sound too right in English and the meaning doesn't seem to be sent across as well either.

I know that a translation could be "So you are only like this" but I would like to have a shorter translation.

Comment: iciba： nothing more than this ； merely thus，examples have：That was／is all there was／is，So much for，that's all，just like this，

Comment: "It is overrated."

Answer (score 5):

There is no 100% 1:1 translation, so how you translate this expression will heavily depend on the context.

Some examples:

You want to fly abroad on holiday, but the airport is closed. You can express your discontent with `坐飞机去旅游原来不过如此。`"So much for taking the plane to go on holiday!".

There is a `...也不过如此` form, that is used often. E.g.
 `最多再有几分钟, 也不过如此.` `"Only a matter of a few more minutes, that's all."`

But this can also have the meaning "like a ....!"
`皇宫也不过如此吧！` `"It's like a palace!"` (lit. Even the imperial palace can not keep up with this).

Answer (score 0):

You really need to put the context in which this is said to achieve a good interpretation.

iciba: 最多再有几英里, 也不过如此.

也不过如此. = that's all.

Answer (score 0):

不过如此 ＝ not a big deal; it's just like this.